# puppeteerによるスクリーンショットのエラーの原因がわからない

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

JavaScriptのpuppeteerの勉強中です。
キンドル本にあったプログラムを真似ています。
vusual studio codeでjavascriptを作成していますが、
ただし、以下のエラーが表記されます。
どこに不備があるかご教示していただけますと助かります。
問題なければ、yahooのスクリーンショットが作成されるようです。
宜しくお願いします。

**ソースコード**

```
const puppeteer = require(' puppeteer');
(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer. launch();
const page = await browser. newPage();
await page. setViewport({ width: 1200, height: 800});
await page. goto(' https:// www. yahoo. co. jp/');
await page. screenshot({ path: 'yahoo. png', fullPage: true});
await browser. close();
})();
```

**エラー内容**

```
    C:\Users\●●●\Documents\javascript>node test001.js
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023
      throw err;
      ^

    Error: Cannot find module ' puppeteer'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\●●●\Documents\javascript\test001.js
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1020:15)

        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:890:27)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:19)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\●●●\Documents\javascript\test001.js:1:19)        
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10) 
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71
    :12) {
      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: [  'C:\\Users\\●●●\\Documents\\javascript\\test001.js' ]    
    }
```

Comment: 質問にあるソースコードにいくつも打ち間違いがあります。`awaist`や`awit`ではなく、`await`です。`reqire('ppuppeteer');` ではなく、`require("puppeteer");` です。打ち間違いをまずは確認してみましょう。また、エラー内容が正しいエラーログになっていないので、実行した結果をそのままコピー＆ペーストすると良いでしょう。

Comment: 大変お恥ずかしい箇所指摘ありがとうございます。修正してエラーを追記しました

Comment: コードとして成立していないところが多々あります、`require(' puppeteer')`ではなく`require('puppeteer')`です。`puppeteer. launch`ではなく、`puppeteer.launch`です。スペース1つ1つにも意味がありますので、正確に写経してみてください。

Comment: himenonさん、超初歩的なミスの、ご指摘感謝しております。ご指摘箇所以外でも不要なスペースがあったので修正したところ、png形式でスクリーンショットできました。2日前から悩んでましたので、やっとスカッとしました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 自己解決されたようで良かったです。頑張ってください。また、回答の方に自己解決済みであることを残しておきましょう。